# Unable to get a Fragment Object into MainActivity : android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have created an experimental app in which I'm trying to learn to establish a successful communication b/w two fragments.

What I have is just one activity which is Main Activity. In this activity I have a view pager element in XML. I've created custom pager adapter which extends to Fragment Pager Adapter and two Fragments which are children and supplied by my pager adapter to the view pager.

What I'm trying to do is: FirstFragment has one button which on clicked changes the background color of the SecondFragment(there's a relative layout as parent), which will be visible on one swipe.

What I've done so far: I created an interface in FirstFragment, implemented in MainActivity, created a method in SecondFragment which changes the background color of layout and finally getting the SecondFragment in MainActivvity (at least trying to) and calling its method. But app is crashing on button click saying "Fragment SecondFragment not attached to a context"

Here's the code:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.laboratory;

import...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FirstFragment.MyListener {

    ViewPager viewPager;
    MyPagerAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void changeColor() {
        SecondFragment secondFragment = new SecondFragment();
        secondFragment.changeColor();
    }
}
```

Custom Adapter:

```
package com.example.android.laboratory;

import ...

public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {

        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                return new FirstFragment();
            case 1:
                return new SecondFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

First Fragment:

```
package com.example.android.laboratory;

import ...

public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    MyListener listener;

    public FirstFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);

        Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listener.changeColor();
            }
        });


        return view;
    }

    public interface MyListener{
        void changeColor();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            listener = (MyListener) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(getActivity().toString() + " must implement MyListener interface.");
        }
    }
}
```

Second Fragment:

```
package com.example.android.laboratory;

import ...

public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

    public SecondFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);

        relativeLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.layout);

        return view;
    }

    public void changeColor() {
        relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    }

}
```

Crash log:

```
12-23 12:18:03.574 31428-31428/com.example.android.laboratory E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.laboratory, PID: 31428
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment SecondFragment{2bfa6ff2} not attached to a context.
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.requireContext(Fragment.java:696)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:760)
        at com.example.android.laboratory.SecondFragment.changeColor(SecondFragment.java:32)
        at com.example.android.laboratory.MainActivity.changeColor(MainActivity.java:28)
        at com.example.android.laboratory.FirstFragment$1.onClick(FirstFragment.java:31)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4791)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19903)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5296)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707)
```

Comment: In the method MainActivity.changeColor you only create SecondFragment but don't attach it to the activity, so Fragment doesn't have context and crashes as you can see in this line of log: at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.requireContext(Fragment.java:696)

Comment: By the way, this approach doesn't help you because method getItem() will return NEW fragment which will know nothing about your color.

Comment: So what do I do?

Comment: I believe there is a lot of ways. As for me, I'd create a new model class which contains all states of your fragments including color. First fragment changes this model and second fragment uses it.

Comment: Are you referring to the view model stated in android documentation?

Comment: See answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see this doc https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating
If you want to make you own bicycle for some reasons, you could try something like this (observer pattern)

MyModel

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyModel {
private int color = R.color.colorPrimary;

private ArrayList<MyObserver> observers = new ArrayList<>();

interface MyObserver {
    void setColor(int color);
}

public void setColor(int color) {
    this.color = color;
    for (int i = 0; i < observers.size(); i++) {
        observers.get(i).setColor(color);
    }
}

public void addObserver(MyObserver newObserver) {
    if (observers.indexOf(newObserver) < 0) {
        observers.add(newObserver);
    }
}

public void deleteObserver(MyObserver oldObserver) {
    if (observers.indexOf(oldObserver) >  -1) {
        observers.remove(oldObserver);
    }
}
}
```

FirstFragment

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);

    Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
            mainActivity.myModel.setColor(R.color.colorAccent);
        }
    });


    return view;
}
}
```

SecondFragment

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment implements MyModel.MyObserver {

RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);

    relativeLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.layout);
    MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    mainActivity.myModel.addObserver(this);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    mainActivity.myModel.deleteObserver(this);
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void setColor(int color) {
    relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(color, null));
}
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ViewPager viewPager;
MyPagerAdapter adapter;

public MyModel myModel = new MyModel();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

}
}
```